# How to know/set the frequency at which the images are taken (grabbed)?

Tags: image-processing, frame-rate, ros

I already posted this question on ros forum, but I would like to post it here again in order to cover a larger audience.

The issue is that I find that the frequency, I compute from the time between two successive callbacks and that from using rostopic hz, is totally different...

With `rostopic hz /pg_15508342/image_raw` I get:

```
average rate: 99.681
    min: 0.003s max: 0.017s std dev: 0.00093s window: 797
average rate: 99.683
    min: 0.003s max: 0.017s std dev: 0.00098s window: 896
average rate: 99.682
    min: 0.003s max: 0.017s std dev: 0.00100s window: 997
average rate: 99.682
    min: 0.003s max: 0.017s std dev: 0.00098s window: 1097
average rate: 99.684
    min: 0.002s max: 0.018s std dev: 0.00102s window: 1196
average rate: 99.681
    min: 0.002s max: 0.018s std dev: 0.00106s window: 1296
average rate: 99.676
```

However, from this very short code, that computes the frequency at which the callback of the same topic is called,

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#include <time.h>
#include <boost/timer.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/version.hpp>
#include  "boost/bind.hpp"
#include  "boost/bind.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

boost::posix_time::ptime time1; 
boost::posix_time::time_duration timeloop;
double timeloop_sc;

int image_itr(0);

void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
{
     //---
      if(image_itr == 0)
        time1 = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();

      timeloop =  boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time() - time1;
  time1 = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
  timeloop_sc = 1e-3* (double)timeloop.total_milliseconds();
  cout << "itr " << image_itr++ << "   fps: " << 1.0/timeloop_sc << endl;

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "image_listener");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  cv::namedWindow("view");
  cv::startWindowThread();
  image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);
  image_transport::Subscriber sub = it.subscribe("/pg_15508342/image_raw", 1, imageCallback);
  ros::spin();
  cv::destroyWindow("view");
}
```

I get this inconsistent result

```
itr 2198   fps: 100
itr 2199   fps: 111.111
itr 2200   fps: 90.9091
itr 2201   fps: 111.111
itr 2202   fps: 111.111
itr 2203   fps: 111.111
itr 2204   fps: 100
itr 2205   fps: 111.111
itr 2206   fps: 100
itr 2207   fps: 100
itr 2208   fps: 90.9091
itr 2209   fps: 125
itr 2210   fps: 100.
```

Why this difference of values?

Also, if I run this same code, but only adding `cv::imshowfrom`, from another host machine,  I get even a quite different value. To be more clear, assume that am using `local` machine, whereas my ros node is implemented and compiled on `onboard` machine. Am doing this from `local`:

```
ssh onboard@ip
rosrun package node
```

Perhaps that `cv::imshowfrom` is consuming a lot of the bandwidth.... yet the code should be running on `onboard` machine not on `local` machine, thus the computational time should have been the same.

For info, am using a Point Grey camera, Chameleon 3. As for the driver, am using ROS flea3 node, from  Kumar robotics driver https://github.com/KumarRobotics/flea3. Am running this on ubuntu 16, 4.6.4-040604-lowlatency kernel.

Comment: How are all those tags related to your question? It is not a C++ question. It is not a ssh question...

Comment: @AndersLindén I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that your estimation of the callback calls time is not exactly what `rostopic hz` is doing. In order to have a closer one, try just computing the delay between callback calls without any further processing. This will avoid the extra calculation time.

```
void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
{
 if(image_itr == 0)
        time1 = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();

  timeloop =  boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time() - time1;
  time1 = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
  timeloop_sc = 1e-3* (double)timeloop.total_milliseconds();
  cout << "itr " << image_itr++ << "   fps: " << 1.0/timeloop_sc << endl;
}
```

Also, set the callback queue size for a higher value, thus avoiding  dropping images due to the little queue size.

```
image_transport::Subscriber sub = it.subscribe("/pg_15508342/image_raw", 1000, imageCallback);
```

Also, I think it would be helpful if you mention the camera type and driver that you are using under ROS.

Hope that helps !

Comment: I found I did a stupid mistake. In fact those 30 fps was due to command `waitKey(30)`. I completely remove that part now.... but am still having inconsistency issues. Am updating my quesiton